# Communicating an error between two separate voids (C#)

Tags: c#, error-handling

I am not sure if what I am trying to do is even possible, but I figure there must be some work around for it. Assume two routines; routine A and routine B. Both routines A, and B have their own try-catch statements. Routine A will call routine B (shown below), and if routine B encounters some error, routine A will be notified of it.

**Here is my example:**

```
// Routine A
private void button13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        somevoid();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.message); // Never makes it here ...
    }
}

// Routine B
private void somevoid()
{
    try
    {
        int i = 1;
        int z = 0;
        int g = i / z;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but it seems, you need to catch the exception in both try catch blocks.  If so, change your code as follows:

```
private void somevoid()
        {

            try
            {
                int i = 1;
                int z = 0;
                int g = i / z;
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don throw ex, that way you will loose the stacktrace information, because you basicaly throw a new exception, just reusing the old one. just throw is enough.

Comment: Not good.  `throw ex` will kill the stack trace. You're better off just doing `throw`.

Comment: @platon Thank you this is perfect. The other answers are  spot on too - thank you guys! Also I feel the need to specify the fact that this is a form app as people (always!) complain about not knowing...

Comment: Yes, you are right!  _throw ex_ will kill the stack :(.  The throw is better.  I'll update my code.

Answer (score 2):

Well you could rethrow the exception in your routine B, like

```
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }
```

That way Routine A can also handle that exception.

Btw, this has nothing to do with winforms, i would remove that flag.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you should simple throw an exception on the catch block of the Routine B like that:

```
 ....
 Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
 throw new InvalidOperationException();
.....
```

then the Try block of routine a will catch the exception

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the try...catch blocks from your routine B. That way, if there is an exception in routine B, it will jump to the catch block in your routine A.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exception to bubble up to `button13_Click` then remove the `try-catch` from `somevoid`. If you intend to actually have the exception re-thrown in Routine A, then you must:

```
throw new Exception;  // if you wish, you could have a custom exception here
```

or...

```
throw;  // to simply re-throw the exception
```

within the catch block of Routine B.

Answer (score 0):

Insert requisite comment about not swallowing exceptions here.

Now on to answering your question: there are a few things you can do here.

I've seen that some answers have been posted about re-throwing the exception.

You can also throw a specific type of exception (of your own creation) that you can explicitly catch -- this gives you an extra degree of control and specificity.

You could also return `bool` from method B as an indicator of success or failure. You don't have to actually use that every place where you call method B, but if you would do things differently in method A depending on whether method B succeeds or fails, you can check that result. You'd just return `true` at the very end of the `try` block and `false` at the end of the `catch` block.